# how to initialize a new object of class in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Dim objConn As New Pclient.Connection
```

Above command creates new object for Pclient class. but how to do the same in C#

It is creating a new object in VB, but how to write in C#

Comment: `var objConn = new Pclient.Connection();` You should pick up some tutorials and/or books on C#, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask about every little syntax detail for a programming language.

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 5):

```
var objConn = new Pclient.Connection();
```

or you can specify the type

```
  Pclient.Connection  objConn = new Pclient.Connection();
```

you can try online converters like

1. [developerfusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)
2. [converter telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)

and also you better learn [Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

---

**vb.net**

```
Dim hero As New SuperHero

With hero 
  .Name = "SpamMan" 
  .PowerLevel = 3 
End With
```

[in Visual Studio 2008 +](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531244%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
Dim hero As New superhero With {.Name = "SpamMan", .PowerLevel = 3}
```

---

**C#**

```
SuperHero hero = new SuperHero() { Name = "SpamMan", PowerLevel = 3 };
```

sample code taken from [VB.NET and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Comment: VB also does the one line version: `Dim hero As New superhero With {.Name = "SpamMan", .PowerLevel = 3}`  in more recent VS versions